# Terminal and unity launcher is missing

Tags: ubuntu, python, gnome-terminal, python3

My python script containing `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` was not working and one of my classmate suggested to remove one of the python packages. (My dell ubuntu 12.04 desktop has two python programme 2.7 and 3) So, I run the command `sudo apt-get remove python`. Now my terminal and unity launcher is missing. How can I recover everything without reinstalling? I can login in `tty` .

Thank you in advance.

(P.S. I understand removing python was a bad idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

that should install the base meta-package with all the dependencies,but since you are using 12.04, if that does not work, try:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: i run the command  "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop". Result shows "E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem." Please suggest a way to fix this problem without upgrading.

Comment: try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, the main problem is that 12.04 is not maintained any more, that makes very hard to solve a really easy problem

Comment: "E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify  a solution)" Result after running sudo dpkg --configure -a followed by sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop